# VBA or Excel Macro to add 1year

Tags: excel, datetime, vba

I have an Excel Spreadsheet that I want to add 1 year to the date in a cell.

Cell B3 currently has a value of 1/1/2014

Would like to create a Macro that will change this date to 1/1/2015

Seems easy enough but my search for this have not given desired results. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your cell and run:

```
Sub dateFixer()
    Dim d As Date
    d = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Value = DateSerial(Year(d) + 1, Month(d), Day(d))
End Sub
```